# Manage application (Office 365) access with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm totally new with this tool, and I have an Azure AD to manage. My main task is to find a way to authorize certain applications from the Office 365 package. But not only that, I have to manage if the user has the right to certain actions from the O365 package. Like creating a Communication Site with SharePoint. That is what I call an action from the SharePoint application, and I have to manage this.

How I can make this happen?

Thanks for you anwsers.